# Create new Table when submit the form

Tags: sql, insert

I have this table :

```
propertyTable - ( id, property , owner_name , date , location)
```

and this is  my input statement :

```
id : _________
property : ________
owner_name : _________
date : _________
location : ________

SUBMIT
```

then, each time the user submits the form I want the system to create a new table like this :

```
ownerTable - ( owner_name , date , location)
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: i wnt to create php like that..i didt know how to create new table when the form is submitted

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how you should ask questions. At the moment it's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: thanks..sory bout that.. i'll edit this post later